# Swift How to reach Group path?

Tags: swift, file, directory

I need to reach a group path named A1 but i cant reach with

```
let dersNotlariUrl =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "A1", withExtension: nil, subdirectory: "View")
```

After i take the path, i need to use this group's files name in the tableView. files are .doc, i will check them with quickLook.

```
let dersNotlariUrl =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "A1", withExtension: nil, subdirectory: nil) 
func getData() {
        
        
        if let url = dersNotlariUrl {
            print("URL for A1 folder: \(url)")
        } else {
            print("Error: A1 folder does not exist in app bundle")
            return
        }
        
        guard let dersNotlariUrl = dersNotlariUrl, FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dersNotlariUrl.path) else {
            print("Error: A1 folder does not exist at path \(dersNotlariUrl?.path ?? "")")
            return
        }

        do {
            files = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: dersNotlariUrl.path)
            mainView.tableView.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("Error while enumerating files in A1 group: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

if i give the computers path just like :/users/ardacmen/....etcetc it's working on my computer but in the real phone it's not working well you know :D

[groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DC0Xh.jpg)

Comment: I don't get it, is A1 a folder in the apps resource bundle or is it an external folder?

Comment: Start by looking at the file structure of your built app. Are your resources organized as expected? If so, post what that file structure actually looks like (not from your Xcode project but from the actual ipa file).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson it's app's resource, i add folder to xcode

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i added group managements ss, can you check it?

Comment: @HangarRash i cannot check it from ipa file because it's not seeable, it include just some plist files

Comment: yeah i look at the documentation for Bundle, i tried everything what can i  try

Comment: @ArdaEminÇimen What do you mean that it "isn't seeable"? Sure it is. In Xcode click on the Product menu and select "Show Build Folder in Finder". Then in the new Finder window the "Build" folder will be selected. Click on "Products" then "Debug-XXX" where XXX is appropriate to your build. Then right-click on your app and select "Show Package Contents". You are now seeing the inside of the ipa. Look for your resources. Are they in a folder as expected?

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is creating groups in Xcode, A1, B1 etc but those groups are only used for helping you organising your files in the Xcode project and has nothing to do with how your build app is structured so all files in them will be placed at the top level in your main bundle.

To create actual folders that will be included in your app you need to add the folders containing the files from Finder to Xcode.

So open a Finder window containing the folder and drag it into your project. A dialog will show and make sure you select

> Create folder reference

for the *Added folders:* setting. The added folder will be coloured blue unlike your Xcode group folders so it's easy to distinguish between them.

After that you can access the content using the folder name

```
let urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: nil, subdirectory: "A1")
```

or

```
let paths = Bundle.main.paths(forResourcesOfType: nil, inDirectory: "A1")
```